# Does multiple read command in conditional loop creates issue in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, scripting

I have one program which goes like :

```
fun_a()
{
    echo "other statement" 
    read user_input
    if [[( $user_input == "Y" ) || ( $user_input == "y" )]];then
        fun_b
    else
        ......
    fi
}
fun_b()
{
    echo "some other statement"
    echo "any statement"
    read user_inp
    if [[( $user_inp == "Y" ) || ( $user_inp == "y" )]];then
    do something
    else
        ..........
    fi
}
echo "any statement"
read user_inp
if [[( $user_inp == "Y" ) || ( $user_inp == "y" )]];then
    fun_a
else
    ......
fi
```

I am not getting expected output from the "read" command. Is it because of the fact that none of the if block is getting closed before the next read statement has been called. If it is so Kindly suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read every time and you don't need to check "Y" in every function actually. As following script, you can see "read" only need one time.

```
#!/bin/bash
fun_a()
{
    echo 'function_a'
    echo "Input: ";read content2
    echo 'content2: ' $content2
    echo 'content: '$content
}
echo "Input: "; read content
echo 'content: '$content
fun_a

>>> ./script.sh
Input:
first
content: first
function_a
Input:
second
content2:  second
content: first
```

Comment: Eric, requirement is like that only, unless user don't want to proceed, we should not proceed & current function should be calling the next function on user input only. Moreover apart from printing one line there are lots of stuff there. There  are o/p's which is getting generated there is being carried to the next function if user i/p is Y.

Comment: Then I will recommend you create one more function 
"read user_input
    if [[( $user_input == "Y" ) || ( $user_input == "y" )]]
return XXX"
Then you can simply use the return value decide what to do. Do you know how to modify?